# Theta notation, complicated proofs

Tags: asymptotics

Problem: To prove
$$2n^2 2^n +n\log n=\Theta(n^2 2^n)$$

I initially started by trying to prove the upper bound, and the way I thought for doing this was by principle of mathematical induction, considering 
$$4n^2 2^n \geq  2n^2 2^n + n\log n.$$ However this proof gets fairly complicated.
Here is my approach:

Upper Bound:
Let $c=3$, then:
$$3n^2 2^n =2n^2 2^n + n^2 2^n \geq 2n^2 2^n + n\log n$$
$$n^2 2^n \geq n\log n$$
$$n 2^n \geq \log n.$$

The last one is true since:
$$n \geq \log n ~\forall n\geq 1.$$

Similarly I have proved for the lower bound with $c=1$. My question is, is this proof sufficient or would I have to prove $n>\log n$ for $n>1$ as well?
And if yes do I do that using derivatives?

Also, I have a great difficulty in proving
$$\frac{6n^3}{\log(n+1)} =\Theta(n^3).$$ Please help me out with this too.

EDIT: The above 2 have been solved.

Last problem: While going about proving
$$n^k n^e + n^k logn = \Theta(n^k n^e)$$ for all k and e >0
For proving the upper bound I take the constant k but how can I prove
$$kn^e > logn$$ for 1>e>0

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your first proof. If you wanted, you could prove $n \geq \log n$ by induction. I'm not sure if the second one holds; it may be $O(n^3)$, not $\Theta(n^3)$.

Comment: Do not significantly change your questions. Especially not after you've received an answer.